# cannot start mysql using --login-path on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, debian, login

On a ubuntu-18.04 system on which mysql 5.7 was installed from a package, I can start mysql (the cmd line tool, not mysqld) using the following:

```
ls -l /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
-rw------- 1 root root 317 Jul 30 06:05 /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
sudo mysql --login-path=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2108
Server version: 5.7.39-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 (Ubuntu)
...
mysql> quit;
```

However, on a ubuntu-20.04 system where I had to install mysql 5.7 via [this](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-mysql-5-7-on-ubuntu-20-04) mechanism, there was no /etc/mysql/debian.cnf.  So I started mysql as root, added the debian-sys-maint user, and created debian.cnf.  There is no actual debian-sys-maint user on either system.

However, I can't start mysql on the ubuntu-20 system using --login-path:

```
$ ls -l /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
-rw------- 1 root root 257 Aug 25 23:37 /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
$ sudo mysql --login-path=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Yet I can start mysql using:

```
$ mysql -u debian-sys-maint -pxxx
```

where xxx is the password value in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf

What am I missing?

Comment: I suspect what you actually need is https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_defaults-file , not https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_login-path